# Mercurial: Moving bookmark without modifying files?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to move a bookmark from one head to another without committing any file changes? I've tried:

```
hg update <destination-head>
hg bookmark bookmark-to-move -f
hg commit
```

But Mercurial complains `nothing changed` and when I try to `hg push -f` I get `no changes found`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `-B` flag to `hg push` in order to make it move the bookmark.

If a bookmark is already exported (present in both source and destination), then a simple `hg push` will move the bookmark forward in the destination. In your case, the local bookmark is not a descendant of the remote bookmark, and so `hg push` alone will no move it.

Using

```
hg push -B bookmark-to-move
```

will work and move the remote bookmark as you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can also run

```
hg bookmark -r . yourbookmark
hg update yourbookmark
```